# How can I solve this delegate error?

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates

I have a delegate, but it doesn't work without the other delegate line in it:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data delegate:(id <ParseOperationDelegate>)theDelegate {

    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        self.dataToParse = data;
        self.delegate = theDelegate;
    }

    appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}
```

It should load data in a Cell but the data isn't shown before the first scroll. What can I do?

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"productCell";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"placeholderCell";

    int nodeCount = [appDelegate.products count];

    if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading...";

        return cell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (nodeCount > 0) {
        XMLProductView *listedProduct = [appDelegate.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = listedProduct.name;
        // cell.detailTextLabel.text = appRecord.artist;

        if (!listedProduct.productImage) {
            if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO) {
                [self startImageDownload:listedProduct forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            UIImageView *listedImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            listedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
        }
        else {
            UIImageView *listedImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            listedImage.image = listedProduct.productImage;
        }

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please be more specific, what is the other delegate line?

Comment: and when you say "it should load data in a cell", I don't see code for that.  Do we need to see the code for your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method too?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith my PaseOperationDelegate is a private id delegate. when I remove appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)... the cell doesn't even get filled. this is my problem.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann please have a look.

Comment: Since your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method references `appDelegate`, why are you surprised that it doesn't work when that's not set?

Comment: i dont understand whats the problem that you are having

Comment: @KenThomases I know. but do you see a problem, why the rows are loaded incorrectly?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith The rows are loaded incorrectly (7/34 are shown AND just after first scroll) :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code seems that its waiting for some event, or some files to get fetched or downloaded, so you will need to call `[tableview reloadData];` when this data is downloaded,

I cant figure it out from the code, but my guts tells me this

1st:
that you are waiting for data from int `nodeCount = [appDelegate.products count];` to be ready, so you will need to have some sort of delegate that gets called when this data is ready

2nd:
you are waiting for an image to get downloaded here `[self startImageDownload:listedProduct forIndexPath:indexPath]`, so when this actually get downloaded you will need to set the image to that cell or `reloadData` on the table

That is what i can figure out from the code.